# Защищенная передача данных

Tags: сервер, сеть, балансировка

Есть балансировщик сети, есть мониторинг сервер и есть серверы, которые ко всему этому подключены. Как можно организовать защищенное соединение между ними, если у серверов ip белые, чтобы юзеры извне не могли подключаться к серверам в обход балансировщика, но без потери скорости?

Answer (score 1):

Настроить на серверах iptables, чтобы отстреливали трафик не от балансировщика.